# cPanel can be setted up for Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, cpanel

After googling, I found that cPanel is available and free for CentOS.
Could you please tell me if it's similar to Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows 10.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

cPanel is an online Linux-based web hosting control panel. Although there are alternative web hosting control panels for Windows such as [Plesk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesk), cPanel does not support Windows. cPanel supports Linux, iOS and Android, but it does not support any Microsoft platforms.